# "Cannot POST" en node.js y postman

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, nodejs, postman

Sucede que tengo este código, en donde intento pasar por parámetro el usuario y la contraseña usando como herramienta Postman. Honestamente soy nuevo en esto entonces no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o el código está mal ya que me da este error en Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
app.post('api/v1/Login/:user/:pass',function(request, res){


 var usuario = request.params.user;
  var contraseña = request.params.pass;

  var request = new sql.Request();
  try{

  request.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.[Client] WHERE username = '"+UsuarioReg+"'AND pass = '"+ContraReg+"'", function (err, recordset) {
    if(err){
    console.log(err);
    }else{
      if(recordset.rowsAffected > 0){
        res.send(JSON.stringify("Usuario identificado correctamente"))
        res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset))
        console.log("Usuario identificado correctamente")
      }else{
        console.log("Usuario ["+UsuarioReg+"] no existe")
      }
    }
  })
}catch(err){
  res.send(JSON.stringify("Error while querying database :- "+err))
  console.log("Error while querying database :- "+err)
}

});
```

Me gustaría saber qué pasa y como solucionarlo! Perdón si la pregunta no está muy clara.

Comment: Intente enviarle los parámetros en la URL. Ejemplo: `api/v1/Login/usuario/contrasena`

Comment: Cambia de POST a GET

Comment: @ValVert no sería recomendable enviar por GET un usuario y contraseña, queda totalmente expuesto. Amigo java005, cuando usas `api/v1/Login/:user/:pass` le estás indicando que vas a pasar por la URL los parámetros y no por el `body`, es por eso que no te encuentra la ruta. Esos parámetros los debes enviar en un json y recibirlos en el back-end leyendo ese json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi primer recomendación es que hagas caso omiso a los comentarios de Mauricio Arias y Valvert, nunca debes enviar información sensible por la URL y menos con un método `GET`, mucho menos cuando se trata de usuarios y contraseñas.

---

El problema que actualmente presentas es debido a que envías los parámetros por medio de la url, lo cual no es correcto y por eso te envía el error, básicamente significa que no encuentra en *endpoint* que solicitas desde Postman.

Para lograr lo que necesitas, para enviar datos por un método `POST` puedes hacer uso del módulo [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), su uso e implementación son bastante sencillos:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.post('/login', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body)
        return res.sendStatus(400)
    console.log(req.body);

    var user = req.body.user;
    res.send('Bienvenido ' + user)
})
```

Para hacer el llamado al *endpoint* desde Postman sería de la siguiente manera:

> - URL: http://localhost:{puerto}/login   (deberías reemplazar `{puerto}` por el que uses actualmente en tu localhost
>
>   - Method: `POST`
>   - Headers:
>       Content-type: application/json
>   - Body:
>
>     ```
>         {
>             "user" : "myuser",
>             "pass":"mypass"
>         }
>     ```

Salida en la consola  sería:

> { user: 'myuser', pass: 'mypass' }

La respuesta en el Postman sería:

> Bienvenido myuser

---

Haciendo el ajuste total, tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
app.post('/login', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body)
        return res.sendStatus(400)

    var user = req.body.user;
    var pass = req.body.pass;

    var request = new sql.Request();
    try {
        request.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.[Client] WHERE username = '" + user + "'AND pass = '" + pass + "'", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                if (recordset.rowsAffected > 0) {
                    res.send(JSON.stringify("Usuario identificado correctamente"))
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset))
                    console.log("Usuario identificado correctamente")
                } else {
                    console.log("Usuario [" + UsuarioReg + "] no existe")
                }
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify("Error while querying database :- " + err))
        console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err)
    }
})
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente!! Muchas gracias, de verdad lo agradezco!!!

Comment: Me alegra @java005 :D Solo faltaría una cosa por corregir: las consultas no deben ser concatenadas, en la medida de lo posible es mejor usar consultas parametrizadas o Stored Procedures ya que así como está es susceptible SQL Injection. Investiga un poco acerca de esto y cualquier duda que te llegue a generar con gusto la resolvemos ;)

Comment: Me pondre a investigar... muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Podrías basarte en este ejemplo. Para el caso ejecuta un SP

```
exports.moduloValidacion = function(req, res)
{
    var post = {}
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("Log Error"+' '+err.originalError);
            res.status(500).send(err.originalError);
        }
        else
        {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.input('user', req.body.user);
            request.input('pass', req.body.pass);
            request.execute('SPValidaUsuario', (err, result) => {
                if(err){console.log("Log Error"+err.originalError.info.message);
                    res.status(500).send(err.originalError.info)}
                else
                {
                    if(result)
                    {
                        console.log("Log Ok");
                        res.status(200).send(result.recordsets[0])
                    }
                }
                sql.close()
            })
        }                   
    })
};
```

Comment: Considero que tu recomendación solo podría confundir al OP ya que el usuario intenta hacer una llamada POST, posteriormente ejecutar un query, no us SP como lo indicas.